# Validate API with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic for authentication in my app, using the standard User and UserSession models.  I'm building an API into my app, and I want to authenticate API access with a single access token.  In my app, every User `belongs_to` a Company, which `has_many` users.  The API is for access to resources belonging to the company, so I'd like to use one single access token for the whole company.

My initial thought was to add a dummy user to Company that only has permission to access the API, whose single access token the company would then use to grant access to the API.  It doesn't appear that I can set a user's e-mail and password blank with AuthLogic, so this isn't panning out.  My next thought was perhaps I could add `acts_as_authentic` to the company itself, but I'm not sure how this would work.

I really want to use Authlogic for the solution because it integrates nicely with my ACL, and appears to have the functionallity I'm looking for mostly built in.

Is it possible to have two models that `act_as_authentic`?  Is there an easier way that I'm not thinking of, built into Authlogic?  Is there a way I can use a dummy user for their API key?  Which way should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do this is:

```
class Something
  acts_as_authentic do |m|
    # API keys are auto generated (See +regenerate_api_key+.)
    # The password is not used for authentication (its just an api_key lookup), so a dummy field is used
    m.login_field = :api_key
    m.validate_login_field = false
    m.validate_email_field = false
    m.crypted_password_field = :api_key_hash
    m.require_password_confirmation = false
    m.validate_password_field = false
    m.crypto_provider = ApiKeyCrypto
  end
end

class ApiKeyCrypto
  def self.encrypt(*tokens)
    'X'
  end

  def self.matches?(crypted, *tokens)
    crypted == 'X'
  end
end

#application_controller.rb
def current_session
  return @current_session if defined?(@current_session)
  ...
    format.any(*api_formats) do
      @current_session = SomethingSession.find
    end
  end
  @current_session
end
def api_formats
  [:xml, :json]
end
```

This works great for ActiveResource FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can have two models `acts_as_authentic`. Set up the `Company` with the minimum Authlogic db fields , and use it's `single_access_token` for API access. Note that your API will not know which `User` is using the system, just the `Company`.