# Prevent Authlogic from establishing a session/cookie for non-HTML requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic and Rails 3. On top of the regular browser-based user experience (logging in via form and whatnot), I'd like to implement an API.

Authlogic seems to support single access tokens that don't persist by default. I supply them by adding a GET argument as in:

```
/users.xml?user_credentails=my_single_access_token
```

**Question:** Is there any way I can have Authlogic accept the API key via HTTP Basic Auth? [Highrise](http://developer.37signals.com/highrise/) does something just like this, allowing for:

```
curl -u 605b32dd:X http://sample.highrisehq.com/people/1.xml
```

The same with [Freshbooks](http://developers.freshbooks.com/):

```
curl -u insert_token_here:X https://sample.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in -d '[xml body here]'
```

How I would go about imitating this functionality? I can't even figure out where the input data (postdata from forms, HTTP basic, API token) are taken in. I've boiled it down to a call to `UserSessions.find` with no arguments, but I lose track of it after there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Related question:** I'd also like to disable session persistence (make it so that no cookie is stored) if HTTP basic is used. Any help on this too would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

If you're implementing an API, you could consider building a separate Rack application that is then mounted at '/api/1.0/...' and shares your models.

That way you are not tying yourself into having your API directly related to your public routes, which could be difficult to construct for the API user.

A good approach would be to create a simple Sinatra application that exposes just the methods that you want, and to then create a separate authentication strategy:

```
require 'sinatra'    
require 'active_support' # all the Rails stuff
require 'lib/user' # your User class
require 'sinatra/respond_to' # gem install sinatra-respond_to

Sinatra::Application.register Sinatra::RespondTo

use Rack::Auth::Basic, "API", do |username, password|
  User.find_by_login(username).valid_password?(password)
end

get '/api/1.0/posts' do
  @posts = Post.recent # assuming you have a Post model...

  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.xml { @posts.to_xml }
    wants.to_json { @posts.to_json }
  end
end

get '/api/1.0/users/:id' do
  @user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])

  # Careful here - don't release personal details!
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.xml { @user.to_xml }
    wants.to_json { @user.to_json }
  end
end
```

Versioning your API with a '1.0' (or similar) in the path means that if you change your models you can create a new version of your API without breaking your users' existing code.

Using this you should be able to allow users to authenticate with HTTP Basic in the form:

```
curl -u steven:password http://example.com/api/1.0/users/steven.xml
curl -u steven:password http://example.com/api/1.0/users/steven.json
curl -u steven:password http://example.com/api/1.0/posts.xml
```

To get this running, save it as 'api.rb', and either run it as a Rack Middleware, or create a 'config.ru' file like so:

```
require 'api'
run Sinatra::Application
```

And then from that directory:

```
rackup
```

Comment: Thanks, stef, for your wonderful writeup on API setup in a Rails environment, although it doesn't do much for my question at hand: how to validate the user when the single access token/API is supplied in the HTTP Basic auth string.

Comment: Oh I see - you want to use a token instead of the password... updating to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, stef, for your detailed answer and remarks on an alternative way to set up an API. For that I upvote you. But my question (explicitly, how to force Authlogic to perform this specific function) is still woefully unresolved. I shall continue investigating on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a 100% this is possible in the way your describing without hacking up Authlogic's core functionality.

The first issue your going to have is that authlogic prevents the use of SSO tokens for authentication unless the request is ATOM or RSS to override this you need to pass a config paramater see here: http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Params/Config

To the core issue: I don't see any 'easy' way to handle this functionality, however what you could do for something like curl is pass the user token as a paramater (using the `-G` option) just like you would when visiting the url.

cURL Documentation: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Allowing the single access token/API key site-wide seems to be as easy as having the controller's `single_access_allowed?` method return true.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your question, but I think the answer is a simple "no."  You're mixing two metaphors here.  If you want a secure API key, use the single access token; if you want to use http basic access authentication, you need a different base64 glyph -- and http basic auth isn't particularly secure (unless used over https, which isn't generally practical).

In more detail:

Per the wikipedia, [http basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is intended to provide a username and password in a simple, standard, but fairly insecure base64 encoded glyph.

To use basic auth, then I believe you want to generate the glyph via a simple

```
Base64.encode64("#{user.name}:#{password}")
```

...and I'd probably do this by having the user type their password, since you can't derive the password from the crypted_password that authlogic stores in your database.

But the upshot is that this is a very different beast from the single_access_token, and the two can't be mixed.

Comment: Enabling the single access token to be accepted as an HTTP Basic username (with a dummy password) appears to me to be no less secure than the default Authlogic practice of accepting the single access token as a query string. FYI, SSL is being used for all authenticated requests, but that detail is beyond the scope of my proper question. To clarify my question, I am not looking to "combine" username/password authentication with the API key; I just want to tell Authlogic to accept the API key when it is being supplied via HTTP Basic rather than as a query string attribute.

Comment: I meant that I think it'd work out of the box if you use the actual username and password.  Fair point regarding security.  I wouldn't use the raw single access token either.

Comment: I was troubled about the single_access_key; it didn't smell right that AuthLogic wouldn't allow better security.  So I did a little more research.  This post --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691330/validate-api-with-authlogic -- reassures me on that regard, and looks like it may provide you with the information you need to solve your problem.